# Ubuntu 18.04 won't boot after installing nvidia driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and have installed a new graphics card (NVidia Geforce GTX 1070). After installing the nvidia-430 driver, I am no longer able to boot. The desktop environment freezes and pressing Alt + F2 shows the following message:

"A start job is running for hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)."

When I boot into recovery mode, nvidia-smi shows that the driver is properly installed. This happens for every version of nvidia that is compatible with the GPU (390 to 430)

Comment: Try disabling Secure Boot.

Comment: It's usually helpful to provide the model of the graphics card. Others with the same card can then help.

Comment: Thanks. I tried disabling Secure Boot and that didn't fix the problem.